# Find elements by XPath with fallback

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

```
for products in self.br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='image']/a"):
    self.urls.append(products.get_attribute("href"))
```

This code will find all hrefs links by the class.

My problem that the webpage has a changing source sometimes it can be `//*[@class='image']/a` but sometimes `//*[@class='newPrice']/a`. How can I change the `for` loop to use the other expression if the first xpath option found nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the output in a variable first:

```
links = self.br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='image']/a")
if not links:
    links = self.br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='newPrice']/a")
for products in links:
    self.urls.append(products.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not equivalent to a fallback, but you could use an OR syntax:

```
for products in self.br.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//*[@class='image']/a | //*[@class='newPrice']/a"):
    self.urls.append(products.get_attribute("href"))
```